# Folium choropleth issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, folium, choropleth

I have an error somewhere but cannot figure it out.  Would appreciate some feedback.  Thank you.

df_grp:

```
   Neighborhood  Count
0   BAYVIEW      14303
1   CENTRAL      17666
2   INGLESIDE    11594
3   MISSION      19503
4   NORTHERN     20100
5   PARK          8699
6   RICHMOND      8922
7   SOUTHERN     28445
8   TARAVAL      11325
9   TENDERLOIN    9942
```

code:

```
!wget --quiet https://cocl.us/sanfran_geojson -O san_fran.json
sf_geo = r'san_fran.json'
m = folium.Map(location=[37.773972, -122.431297], zoom_start=12)

m.choropleth(
    geo_data=sf_geo,
    data=df_grp,
    columns=['Neighborhood', 'Count'],
    key_on='feature.properties.name',
    fill_color='YlOrRd', 
    fill_opacity=0.7, 
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='San Francisco Crime by Neighborhood'
)

m
```

[image]

Comment: Could you give *some* details of the error? What did you expect? And what happened instead? Were there any error messages that you could add?

Comment: There was no error message.  I had expected the map to display colors corresponding to the choropleth scale but instead, only got a single color on the map.  Question is resolved as I had the "key" statement set with an incorrect parameter.  Thanks for looking into my problem

Answer (score 1):

The error is in:

`key_on='feature.properties.name',`

Change it to:

`key_on='feature.properties.DISTRICT',`

and you get:

[image]

Comment: I knew it had to be simple but I could not find the answer.  Thank you!  Much appreciated.

Comment: Please, accept my answer if it solves your problem. Thanks.